# Generating numbers

Tags: combinatorics

We can do the following actions: add 1 or 2 and  multiply by 3. Find the minimum number of operations to get an arbitrary natural number N from 0 using these three actions.

My candidate for $k$ would be this function
$$
k(N) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & ; N = 1 \\
1 + k(N/3) &; N \bmod 3 = 0 \\
1 + k(N-2) &;   N \bmod 3 = 2 \\
1 + k(N-1) & ; N \bmod 3 = 1, N > 0
\end{cases}
$$
I want to evaluate the complexity of this algorithm and to show in a way , that this is the best.Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Look at the binary expansion of $N$.

Comment: This is closely linked to your earlier question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715680/generating-numbers  Have you tried to adapt the solution you were given to that one?

Comment: Is the multiplication operation by $2$, as you wrote, or by $3$, as your function $k$ suggests?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: If $L$ is the length of $N$
 in binary and $K$ is the number of ones digits you want $L+K-1$.

Comment: Also, you meant to write $1+k(N-2)$ in the third line and $1+k(N-1)$ in the fourth (assuming, that is, that you are following the answer given you by @mvw in your prior post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Once you fix the third and fourth clauses of the definition of $k$, in which you want $1+k(N-2)$ and $1+k(N-1)$, respectively, you can prove that $k$ is optimal by induction on $n$, though the form of induction that I find easiest to use here is one that you may not have seen. If $k$ is not optimal, let $n$ be the smallest positive integer for which $k(n)$ is greater than the actual minimum number of operations required to reach $n$; we’ll get a contradiction, thereby showing that no such minimum counterexample exists and hence that there is no counterexample at all. Clearly $n>1$.

Suppose that $n$ can be reached in $m<k(n)$ operations, say by the sequence $O_1,O_2,\ldots,O_m$. If $O_m$ is adding $1$, then $n-1$ can be reached in $m-1$ operations. The minimality of $n$ implies that $k(n-1)\le m-1$. But clearly we can reach $n$ in $k(n-1)+1$ operations, so

$$m<k(n)\le k(n-1)+1\le(m-1)+1=m\;,$$

which is absurd. Thus, $O_m$ cannot be adding $1$.

I’ll leave the other two cases to you; they’re very similar.

---

For the approximate magnitude of $k(n)$ in terms of $n$, write $n$ in base three. Suppose that the ternary representation of $n$ is $d_1d_2\ldots d_m$, where $d_1\ne 0$.

- How can you express $m$ in terms of $n$?
- How many times will you have to apply the operation of multiplying by $3$?
- What is the smallest number of times that you could have to apply one of the other two operations?
- What is the largest number of times that you could have to apply one of the other two operations?

The answers to the last three questions are most easily expressed in terms of $m$; you can then use the answer to the first question to express them in terms of $n$.